# Problem with password encoder in the test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

When trying to test a method, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in this line of code:

```java
when(webConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated.getPassword());
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(java.lang.CharSequence)" because the return value of "com.example.paymybuddy.security.WebConfig.passwordEncoder()" is null
```

I have provided a mock of `WebConfig` class but it looks like still missing something. Thank you for your help in advance.

My code:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {
            
    @Mock
    SecurityService securityService;
            
    @Mock
    IUserRepository userRepository;
            
    @Mock
    WebConfig webConfig;
            
    @InjectMocks
    UserService userService;
                   
    @Test
    public void updateProfileTest() {
        UserProfileDTO userDTO = new UserProfileDTO();
        userDTO.setEmail("john@simons");
        userDTO.setFirstName("John");
        userDTO.setLastName("Simons");
        userDTO.setPassword("pass");
        userDTO.setConfirmPassword("pass");
            
        User userForUpdate = new User();
        userForUpdate.setFirstName("Joo");
        userForUpdate.setLastName("Sim");
        userForUpdate.setBalance(242.20);
        userForUpdate.setEmail("john@simons");
        userForUpdate.setPassword("pass");
        userForUpdate.setRole("ROLE_USER");
            
        User userUpdated = new User();
        userUpdated.setFirstName("John");
        userUpdated.setLastName("Simons");
        userUpdated.setBalance(242.20);
        userUpdated.setEmail("john@simons");
        userUpdated.setPassword("pass");
        userUpdated.setRole("ROLE_USER");

        when(userRepository.findByEmail(any())).thenReturn(userForUpdate);
        when(webConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated.getPassword());
        when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated);
            
        User test = userService.updateProfile(userDTO);
        assertEquals("john@simons",test.getEmail());
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
            
    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;
            
    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;
            
    @Autowired
    private WebConfig webConfig;
            
    public User updateProfile (UserProfileDTO userProfileDTO) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(securityService.getLoggedUser());
        user.setFirstName(userProfileDTO.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userProfileDTO.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(securityService.getLoggedUser());
        if(!userProfileDTO.getConfirmPassword().equals(userProfileDTO.getPassword())){
            throw new PasswordException("Password confirmation not match");
        }
              user.setPassword(webConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(userProfileDTO.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
        
    @Bean
    RequestRejectedHandler requestRejectedHandler() {
        return new HttpStatusRequestRejectedHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting the config into your `UserService` but rather a `PasswordEncoder` and mock that.

Comment: That being said, `webConfig.passwordEncoder()` returns `null` because you haven't registered any behavior for that and the default is to return `null`. As that leads to `null` you are trying to invoke `encode` on `null` and that will obviously lead to a `NullPointerException`. But as stated in my initial comment, you shouldb't be injecting that configuration class into your service, but rather a `PasswordEncoder` and mock that.

Answer (score 1):

```java
when(webConfig.passwordEncoder().encode(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated.getPassword());
```

This line is the problem (or more broadly your design but more on that later). `webConfig` is a mock, which means it will intercept all method calls and excert the registered behavior or the default if none. `webConfig.passwordEncoder()` is the first call on yuor mock and you haven't told the mock what to do, hence it will do the default which is to return `null`. You go then on by mocking the `encode` call on the return value, which will fail.

You should either tell Mockito to do something else by default (`@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` instead of plain `@Mock`) or explicitly mock the call to `webConfig.passwordEncoder()` and return a mocked `PasswordEncoder` and then mock behavior on that for `encode`.

However the fact that you inject the `WebConfig` and not a `PasswordEncoder` in your `UserService` is the actual problem (or the problem in your design). You should inject a `PasswordEncoder`.

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
            
    private final SecurityService securityService;
    private final IUserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
            
    public UserService(SecurityService securityService, IUserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
      this.securityService=securityService;
      this.userRepository=userRepository;
      this.encoder=encoder;
    }

    public User updateProfile (UserProfileDTO userProfileDTO) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(securityService.getLoggedUser());
        user.setFirstName(userProfileDTO.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userProfileDTO.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(securityService.getLoggedUser());
        if(!userProfileDTO.getConfirmPassword().equals(userProfileDTO.getPassword())){
            throw new PasswordException("Password confirmation not match");
        }
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(userProfileDTO.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Now you can modify your test as well.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {
            
    @Mock
    SecurityService securityService;
            
    @Mock
    IUserRepository userRepository;
            
    @Mock
    PasswordEncoder encoder;
            
    @InjectMocks
    UserService userService;
                   
    @Test
    public void updateProfileTest() {
        UserProfileDTO userDTO = new UserProfileDTO();
        userDTO.setEmail("john@simons");
        userDTO.setFirstName("John");
        userDTO.setLastName("Simons");
        userDTO.setPassword("pass");
        userDTO.setConfirmPassword("pass");
            
        User userForUpdate = new User();
        userForUpdate.setFirstName("Joo");
        userForUpdate.setLastName("Sim");
        userForUpdate.setBalance(242.20);
        userForUpdate.setEmail("john@simons");
        userForUpdate.setPassword("pass");
        userForUpdate.setRole("ROLE_USER");
            
        User userUpdated = new User();
        userUpdated.setFirstName("John");
        userUpdated.setLastName("Simons");
        userUpdated.setBalance(242.20);
        userUpdated.setEmail("john@simons");
        userUpdated.setPassword("pass");
        userUpdated.setRole("ROLE_USER");

        when(userRepository.findByEmail(any())).thenReturn(userForUpdate);
        when(encoder.encode(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated.getPassword());
        when(userRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(userUpdated);
            
        User test = userService.updateProfile(userDTO);
        assertEquals("john@simons",test.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Now your service just depends on the classes it needs instead of knowing something about the configuration.